# Use XML request in C#

Tags: c#, xml, request

I'm new to XML; I need to do this request to my XML file in C#:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ServiceRequest><filters><Criteria field="name" operator="CONTAINS">XXX</Criteria></filters></ServiceRequest>
```

An example of my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ServiceResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNam
    espaceSchemaLocation="https://xxxxxxxxxxxx">
      <responseCode>SUCCESS</responseCode>
      <count>xxx</count>
      <hasMoreRecords>true</hasMoreRecords>
      <lastId>xxxxxxxx</lastId>
      <data>
 <name>XXXX</name>
      <parentTagId>xxxxxxxx</parentTagId>
      <created>xxxxxxxx</created>
      <modified>xxxxxxxx</modified>
      <ruleText>xxxxxxxx</ruleText>
      <ruleType>xxxxxxxx</ruleType>
      <srcAssetGroupId>xxxxxxxx</srcAssetGroupId>
      <srcBusinessUnitId>xxxxxxxx</srcBusinessUnitId>
    </Tag>
  </data>
```

How can I proceed ?

Comment: 1) Can there be more than one criterion? 2) Please edit your question to include the minimal valid piece of XML which contains a result for that request.

Comment: 1) I just need some item wich their name contains some specific character. 2) It's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to get the <data> element which contains an element of a particular name (in this case, "name").

First you need to parse the request XML to find out what to get from the main XML.

To get the data from the main XML, you can use an [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) expression:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<ServiceResponse xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=""https://xxxxxxxxxxxx"">
    <responseCode>SUCCESS</responseCode>
    <count>xxx</count>
    <hasMoreRecords>true</hasMoreRecords>
    <lastId>xxxxxxxx</lastId>
    <data>
        <name>XXXX</name>
        <parentTagId>xxxxxxxx</parentTagId>
        <created>xxxxxxxx</created>
        <modified>xxxxxxxx</modified>
        <ruleText>xxxxxxxx</ruleText>
        <ruleType>xxxxxxxx</ruleType>
        <srcAssetGroupId>xxxxxxxx</srcAssetGroupId>
        <srcBusinessUnitId>xxxxxxxx</srcBusinessUnitId>
    </data>
    <data>
        <name>YYYY</name>
        <parentTagId>pti</parentTagId>
        <created>c</created>
        <modified>m</modified>
        <ruleText>rt</ruleText>
        <ruleType>rty</ruleType>
        <srcAssetGroupId>a</srcAssetGroupId>
        <srcBusinessUnitId>b</srcBusinessUnitId>
    </data>
</ServiceResponse>";

            string q = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?><ServiceRequest><filters><Criteria field=""name"" operator=""CONTAINS"">XXX</Criteria></filters></ServiceRequest>";
            XDocument qd = XDocument.Parse(q);

            List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>();
            List<string> operators = new List<string>();
            List<string> values = new List<string>();

            foreach(XElement criterion in qd.Descendants("Criteria"))
            {
                fieldNames.Add(criterion.Attribute("field").Value);
                operators.Add(criterion.Attribute("operator").Value);
                values.Add(criterion.Value);
            }

            //TODO: write code to cope with anything other than exactly 1 criterion.
            //TODO: write code for operators other than "contains".

            // Construct an XPath query expression:
            string xq = $"//{fieldNames[0]}[contains(text(), '{values[0]}')]/..";

            XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
            xd.LoadXml(x);

            foreach (XmlNode n in xd.SelectNodes(xq))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n.InnerXml);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
<name>XXXX</name><parentTagId>xxxxxxxx</parentTagId><created>xxxxxxxx</created><modified>xxxxxxxx</modified><ruleText>xxxxxxxx</ruleText><ruleType>xxxxxxxx</ruleType><srcAssetGroupId>xxxxxxxx</srcAssetGroupId><srcBusinessUnitId>xxxxxxxx</srcBusinessUnitId>
```

Comment: Exactly what i want ! Thanx you very much !